# Get Facebook Login Callback C#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

When I'm trying to go to the Login URL that I got from my server app (by using FacebookClient.GetLoginUrl), where I specify a callback url as:

```
http://example.org:8080/login_success
```

There is a HTTP Server running on that target (mydomian.com:8080), which receive the request by the redirecting after I have logged into facebook and granted access to the App that attempting to use facebook on my behalf...

The problem is that the GET Request I receive on my server, got RawUrl = login_succes? but has NO data at all. No QueryString, no notthing...

So when I got to the loginUrl, I get prompted by facebook.com/dialog/oauth, who wants me to login and grant access to the app requesting access. So far so good. Then when succesfully logged in, I should be redirected to the RedirectUrl specified in the loginurl, and that seems fine. The problem is that I don't get any token or something in the GET request I receive at the RedirectUrl target, and since the HTTP Server respond with a 200 OK, the client who granted access now sees:

```
example.org:8080/login_success?#access_token=someaccesstokenvalues&expires_in=xxxxx&code=averylongcodestring
```

What did I miss?? I expected this access_token, expire value and code server-side, and not presented in the URL fields of the client browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify which type of answer you want, via the `response_type` parameter of the login dialog.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#login

If it is set to `token`, then you will get the access token as a hash fragment in the URL – this is for client-side apps.

If it is set to `code`, then you will get a code parameter back, that you can then exchange for an access token via a server-side request.

Comment: Thanks! Thats excatly what I missed. I had the response_type as "code token", so I got both, which seems  to destroy the response, if you want it server-side.

Comment: As the docs state, `code token` still only returns a URL fragment, but it does not only give you the access token in the fragment, but the code as well. (Probably limited uses cases for that though.)